# Are enemies affected by Blind?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The Blind status makes it so you cannot see dice values. Whenever I use Blind on an enemy they seem to still know what the dice values are. Does Blind have any effect on enemies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common feeling, I found a discussion on [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/861540/discussions/0/1661194916749075072/) where several users states that blind status is totally pointless since enemies seem to know the value of the dice.

But there's a suggestion:

> Actually... I saw ONE use for Blind status effects on enemies in Parrallel Universe chapters (the one which hides their HP, which could also be caused by a rule).
> Enemies who can't see their own HP seem to disregard it, leading to them dying to self-damage-effects such as "Shock!?" or regular dice on Fire, thinking they got enough HP to survive those blows.

Comment: Technically that's the Blind? status, not Blind.